# need correct jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I would like to bind a function to this anchor but cannot seem to get the selector right

This didn't work

```
$(function(){
$("a[onclick=='RemoveCCard_OnClick(event);']").bind('click', function() {
alert("");
return false;
});
});



<span style="display: block;" id="span_remove_selected_ccards">
<a style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);" onclick="RemoveCCard_OnClick(event);" href="javascript: void(0);">
<span class="PageText_L31n">remove selected</span></a>
<input type="hidden" value="1968" name="remove_ccardid" id="remove_ccardid">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a much simpler selector here not looking at an `onclick` attribute, like this:

```
$("#span_remove_selected_ccards > a").click(function() {
  return false;
});
```

This uses an [`#ID` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) on the parent element then gets the [`>` (immediate child)](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) `<a>` to bind the event to.  [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is just a shortcut for `.bind('click')` when pass a function.  Also, descending from an ID selector is *much* faster than looking for an attribute, which will crawl all anchors in the page.

Comment: As always Nick you are right on target. I tried something similar and it didn't work $("span#span_remove_selected_ccards > a"). Perhaps I did something wrong. Anyway your selector worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There should be only one '=' as you are using the [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("a[onclick='RemoveCCard_OnClick(event);']").bind('click', function() {
    alert("");
    return false;
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ucHuY/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the attribute selector like that. If you need to attach an event handler to a specific element, give it a `class` or, if it is unique, an `id`, like so:

```
<a id="unique" href="#">Look ma, I'm special!</a>
<a class="many" href="#">You can have lots and lots of me with the same class here</a>
```

Then use the following selectors to select them

```
$('#unique')
$('.many')
```

Comment: That did not answer my question at all. I do not have access to that markup or I would have put an id in the anchor.